# Read words form text file(single word in a line)

Tags: c

I have written the following code in c to read words in a text file, but the code is not working, please correct it.
I have a file a.txt,in it:
Coding

So I want the word 'Coding' to be stored into array b.

```
q=fopen("a.txt","r");
d=fgetc(q);//q is pointer to text file
while(d!=EOF)
          {
            i=0;
            while((d!='\n')&&(d!=EOF));
            {  
                b[i++]=d;
                d=fgetc(q);
            }
            b[i]='\0';
            if(d==EOF)
                 break;
            d=fgetc(q);
         }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: @pcluddite is code correct?

Comment: if it's not working as you say, then it probably isn't.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided how `b` is allocated, and maybe renamed your variables to something more memorable.

Comment: @SteveJobs, the difficulty is you haven't specified how you intend to read the file, From what is in your question, it is apparent you want to read from `a.txt`, and it apparently contains the word `Coding`, but those are **assumptions** because you do not provide `a.txt` so anyone can determine whether it contains more than just `Coding`. You have attempted a *character-oriented* approach with `fgetc`, but if you are reading lines of text `fgets` or POSIX `getline` make more sense. Please add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not `malloc`ating memory, then below would be my approach

```
int c; 
char myword[20]; // max characters to store is 20
int i=0;
FILE* ptr=fopen("38518211","r");
if (ptr==NULL){
printf("Can't open the file");
}
else{
while(i<19 && (c=fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
  myword[i++]=c;
}
if((c=fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
 printf("Original string is truncated to fit into alloted space\n");
myword[i]='\0'; // Null terminating the string
printf("String from file %s\n",myword);
fclose(ptr);
```